# Modelling approaches for sequences

Tags: regression, time-series, modeling

I have a dataset related to the time taken for vehicles to arrive at their destination, at unevenly spaced points of the journey (on a particular route(s)). For example (made up, but actual dataset has ~1000s  of records shared across ~100 trips):

| time to dest | distance to dest | trip id | other features ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 7 | 0 | ... |
| 2 | 4 | 0 | ... |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | ... |
| 6 | 8 | 1 | ... |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | ... |

Each trip is essentially a sequence with potentially different lengths/# records, and different trip start / end times.

The goal is to predict the time to destination of a new vehicle (unseen trip id) at various points of its trip (and examine which features are relevant).

I was wondering about how to approach modelling in this situation. It seems that standard time-series modelling (ARIMA etc.) is not appropriate given the uneven sampling per trip, and the fact that we have multiple trips/series that a model should preferably train together on. A regular linear regression model might not be good either, given that records from the same trip are very likely correlated.

Would a mixed effects model be useful in this situation? That is, using trip id as a random effect category. How would that work for new, unseen trips?

Thank you for the help, I am new to this type of situation.